# Nasty Segue Error Message While Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, segue

I am relatively new to Swift and iOS in general.  When I create a segue from a button to another view, I get a nasty error message (below).  Can someone help me decipher this?

```
2016-04-17 16:25:49.133 FoodPin[9322:676896] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-u9a-Ka-ctP" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d58d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104afcdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d58cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010396e4e2 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 638
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010371b560 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010372193b -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 120
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000103751750 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1203
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000103761b9b -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000103762d0b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000103911503 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010363b980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108006c00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107ffb08e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107ffaf0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107fef3c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010801d086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010801d7f8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c7dc37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c7dba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c737fb __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c730f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001073eead2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000103580f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    23  FoodPin                             0x0000000102b589f2 main + 114
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001055c092d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem, please share your code

Comment: That scene is using a UITableViewController but the root object in the scene isn't a UITableView.

Comment: Thank you Paulw11. That was exactly my problem. Thanks!